# Horizontal alignment under right-justified text

Tags: horizontal-alignment

At the end of my Acknowledgments section, I would like my name to be right justified. Then, on the next line, I'd like the date to be horizontally aligned with my name. How do I do this?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
]{microtype}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section*{Acknowledgments}
\lipsum[1]

\hspace*{\fill} J.\ J.\ Jingleheimer Schmidt\\
\hspace*{\fill} December 2020

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put name and date in a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
]{microtype}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section*{Acknowledgments}
\lipsum[1]

\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tabular}{l@{}}
J.\ J.\ Jingleheimer Schmidt\\
December 2020
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]